# Is there any sql ha dr solution that allows write to multiple servers?

Tags: sql-server, high-availability, disaster-recovery

I am looking for a sql ha dr solution that allows users to write to multiple replicas. Is this possible in sql server?

For example: AG allows read from multiple replicas. But write only to primary replica.

I couldn't find a way to implement an architecture so that the application using sql server replica can read and write from both servers (like active active writes).

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned, there's not really a standard way to do this in SQL Server, but you can try using Replication to achieve it. Merge Replication allows writing at multiple sources.

[Merge Replication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Subsequent data changes and schema modifications made at the Publisher and Subscribers are tracked with triggers. The Subscriber synchronizes with the Publisher when connected to the network and exchanges all rows that have changed between the Publisher and Subscriber since the last time synchronization occurred.

> Merge replication is appropriate in any of the following situations: Multiple Subscribers might update the same data at various times and propagate those changes to the Publisher and to other Subscribers.

Answer (score -4):

I have not heard something like writing to multiple replicas. As far I know , could be wrong, in sql server we still do not have a feature that will divert application to split write workload like Active Active connection . However you can try giving a read on merge replication if that is what you are looking for .

Comment: I really don’t see a point of negative voting when I already have included Merge replication as an option. Will take as a positive feedback to be more precise in my answer next time . Cheers!!

Answer (score -4):

SQL Server log shipping can ship to more than one instance. The default internal (data gap) is 15 minutes.

(But it might not be acceptable for many cases. Depends on your requirement)

Or you can combine continuous replication to a instance in DR site and then log ship to multiple instances.